# Task WhenAll combined with ContinueWith not work as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a Winform project that inside of the winform class I have a property called DataBindingTasks like so.

```
// create a task list to determine when tasks have finished during load
protected List<Task> DataBindingTasks = new List<Task>();
```

I have several async void methods that I am calling in the winform "Load" event that are all similar to the following.

```
private async void BindSomething(int millSecToWait)
{
    var someTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // do some work
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millSecToWait);

        // return some list for binding
        return new List<int>();
    });
    // add the task to the task list
    DataBindingTasks.Add(someTask);

    // wait until data has loaded
    var listToBind = await someTask;

    // bind the data to a grid
}
```

I am calling the `BindSomething` methods on load.
I say methods because there are several of these binding types of methods that are called on load.

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // async bind something and let UI continue
    // fire and forget
    BindSomething(5000);
    BindSomething(8000);
    BindSomething(2000);
    BindSomething(2000);

    // code to execute when all data binding tasks have completed
    Task.WhenAll(DataBindingTasks).ContinueWith((x) =>
    {
        // Do something after all async binding tasks have completed
    });
}
```

EXCEPT the `ContinueWith` code is executing even though all the tasks have not completed.

Here is a screen shot showing that all task are not complete.

[image]

**UPDATED 10/29**
The problem is obviously deeper than the sample code above and the sample code above does not fully explain the true scenario.

I will try to explain in greater detail but try to not make it to long.

This is a Winform application.
We have created a base winform "BaseForm" that all other winforms will inherit from.
We have overridden the "OnLoad" event in the "BaseForm" so that we can call a new method that all inherited forms will have called "LoadData".
Since "LoadData" can have async method calls, the base form needs to know when the "LoadData" method is finished.
So in the base form was have some of the following:

```
protected List<Task> DataBindingTasks = new List<Task>();

public event EventHandler DataBindingTasksComplete;
protected void OnDataBindingTasksComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    if (DataBindingTasksComplete != null)
    {
        DataBindingTasksComplete(this, e);
    }
    // now clear the list
    DataBindingTasks.Clear();
}

// NOTE: this is inside the OnLoad called before base.OnLoad(e)
Task.WhenAll(DataBindingTasks).ContinueWith((x) =>
{
    OnDataBindingTasksComplete(EventArgs.Empty);
});
```

The hope was that all inherited forms would add any of their "async" tasks to this list so that the base form could fire the "DataBindingTasksComplete" event so they would know that form has finished loading.

The problem "as perceived to us at the time of the issue" was that the "WhenAll().ContinueWith" was not waiting until all the tasks on the list had completed.
BUT as someone noted, the list might have changed.
So here is most likely what happened.
There are 4 "BindSomething" methods that are marked async all called from the Form_Load
The 2nd or so line down inside the "BindSomething" method is used to add a task to the "BaseForm.DataBindingTasks" list.
Since each of these calls are marked async, the Form_Load continues to call all 4 as a "fire and forget".
After that, it returns back to the BaseForm OnLoad which then looks at the "DataBindingTasks" list to see if all tasks have completed.
My best guess is that one of the "BindSomething" methods was in the middle of adding its task to the list yet the Base.OnLoad has already started looking at the list.

I could add 4 "fake" tasks (like thread sleep) to the list even before calling the "BindSomething" methods as "place holders" and then inside the "BindSomething" methods swap out the "fake" tasks with the "real" tasks.
This seams messy and most likely will cause other issues.
The most likely fix is to not use a task list / WhenAll.ContinueWith and instead call the load data with "await" and then raise the event on the next line.

Comment: Your `Load` method only calls `BindSomething` 3 times, and yet you have 4 items in the list, meaning something added an item to the list *after you finished calling `Load`*.  This is why you shouldn't be using data structures at a much larger scope than is actually needed, allowing code that has no business interacting with this operation to see and touch that list.

Comment: `// Do something after all binding is complete` This comment is false.  It should read, "Do something after all of the data to bind has been computed, but possibly before they've actually been bound to the UI", given that the tasks you've added a continuation too are tasks that have merely computed the values to bind, not finished binding them.  This is why you shouldn't be adding an intermediate task to the list, you should simply be returning a `Task` from this method, so that the caller can use it directly (and fixing the previous problem at the same time).

Comment: @Servy The screenshot is from our production application. The code I provide is only a quick example.

Comment: @Servy The List had 4 tasks even before the Task.WhenAll was called. All of the BindSomething methods were called before the Task.WhenAll, there is a slight chance that the WhenAll was executed before the BindSomething return execution.

Comment: If your code is not actually representative of your real code, then that's a problem.  You need to provide code that is able to reproduce your problem, which you have not done.

Comment: @Servy This code is 99.9% close to production code. Here at Stackoverflow we should only post short examples of code to demonstrate the issue. I can't show production code but I can show "example" of the issue. The "FIX" was to change "Task.Factory.Start" to "Task.Run" as stated by VMAtm.  Thank you for all your "HELPFUL" input into the issue.

Comment: Perhaps, but if so the .1% not shown *was what was causing your problem*, because the code shown *doesn't reproduce the problem you have described*.  It can't.  The code that you showed only puts three tasks in the list, and the problem that you're describing is having a fourth task added that is unfinished.  Changing `StartNew` to `Run` **will not fix that problem**.  Your code still has *exactly the same problem it has before*.  `StartNew` doesn't magically add tasks to a list that wouldn't have before that `Run` doesn't.  Your problem still exists, just as it did before.

Comment: The answer that you got is the moral equivalent of telling you to rename your method or to refactor out some logic into a separate method.  It's not bad advice, but it's not a functional change to the behavior of a code, just good practices for more maintainable code.  They are all things that you should do, to be sure, but they haven't fixed your problem.  Your code has race conditions in it, and you need to *fix those race conditions* for your code to reliably produce the correct results.

Comment: @Servy I'm sorry but I don't know what else to say. I was getting the problem in production where ContinueWith was firing when it shouldn't and now after changing "Task.Factory.Start" to "Task.Run" the problem went away in production. It most likely is a timing issue as you suggest and will no double show up again but I honestly don't understand enough about "Tasks" in general to re-write the code we have to make it work "better". I have no doubt that I will be re-writing this methods to return tasks from the methods and then await the tasks in the load event...

Comment: Like I said.  You had, **and still have** a race condition.  The code doesn't *always* fail, and the code doesn't always work.  It sometimes works and it sometimes doesn't.  You could have *changed nothing* and tried it again and had it work.  What you changed didn't fix your problem.  Your problem still exists.  You cannot think that it won't come up again, because there's not basis for that assertion.  You have done **nothing** to fix it; it's just as likely to come up again as it was before you changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async void` methods are called as `fire-and-forget`, and there is no way to wait for them, that's why your delegate don't wait properly - it simply can't do that. So you need some changes in your code.

**Update**: @Servy noted the main problem in your code which I've missed, thanks for him:

```
DataBindingTasks.Add(someTask);
```

This operation isn't **thread-safe**! You simply losing some of your tasks during parallel calls for `Add` method. You need to change this: by using `lock`, by using [`ConcurrentCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-structures-for-parallel-programming) or by using data separation: assign a task to array by different indexes so parallel tasks aren't intersect each other.

First of all, you shouldn't use the `StartNew` in this case, use the `Task.Run`, otherwise you [**can** met some problems in your app](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Second thing is that you can make the `Load` method `async` and `await` it, so your UI wouldn't freeze, and you can switch the signature for your `BindSomething` methods to became awaitable, as @digimunk mentioned:

```
// note that we return the task here
private async Task BindSomething(int millSecToWait)
{
    // use Task.Run in this case
    var someTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Some work
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millSecToWait);
            // return some list for binding
            return new List<int>();
        });

    DataBindingTasks.Add(someTask);

    // wait until data has loaded
    var listToBind = await someTask;

    // bind the data to a grid
}

// async void for the event handler
private async void Load()
{
    // start tasks in fire-and-forget fashion
    BindSomething(5000);
    BindSomething(8000);
    BindSomething(2000);

    // code to execute when all data binding tasks have completed
    await Task.WhenAll(DataBindingTasks);

    // Do something after all binding is complete
}
```

In this case you can `await` the `Load` method safely.

Comment: I don't fully understand why yet but following your suggestion on changing "Task.Factory.StartNew" to "Task.Run" solved my issue.

Comment: Read the linked article - `StartNew` uses the `SynchronizationContext.Current`, that's why some of your tasks actually executes on UI thread.

Comment: All of these methods here are all fire and forget, you claim to have fixed them without actually fixing them.  The code also still continues on before the bindings have actually finished.  Every single change that you've suggested is merely an aesthetic change, and hasn't actually changed the way that the code actually works.

Comment: @goroth Your code still has all of the same race conditions that it had before.  This hasn't fixed them.  At most it's slightly changed the odds that they happen.

Comment: @Servy Oh my, race condition, exactly! Thanks, added that to the answer. But why do you sat that code finishes before binding (apart from race condition)?

Comment: @VMAtm What makes you say that the code always runs *after* the binding?  It is allowed to run before the binding unless there is such a constraint (and there isn't one).

Comment: Oh, and the race condition  you claim exists is not in fact there.  It's a really poorly constructed situation from a design point of view, but in all of the code shown the list is only ever manipulated from a single thread.  If there is code accessing the list from another thread, it's not shown, so that is not the source OP's race condition.

Comment: Hmm, if I `await Task.WhenAll`, then code which is *after* that line will run *after* binding is complete, no?

Comment: @Servy race condition may happen, as `BindSomething` is called in parallel

Comment: @VMAtm No, it's not called in parallel, as I said in my comment, the list is only ever manipulated from a single thread in the code shown.  If there is code manipulating it from another thread, it's not in the code shown.

Comment: @VMAtm When you call `WhenAll` the task will complete *when all of the tasks provided to it have completed*.  In this case, that is not when the binding has been completed, but rather when the values to be bound have been constructed.

Comment: I think I need some time to reword the answer.

Comment: @VMAtm Thanks for the information on the ConcurrentCollection. I was not aware that it existed.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need .ContinueWith(). Just await the Task.WhenAll(), and then put whatever code you want to run after it under it. Also, change the "void" in the method signature to "async Task".

Comment: While a good practice, this wouldn't change the behavior of the code in question, and wouldn't solve the problem described.

Comment: The tasks are not complete because you didn't await them. Await the Task.WhenAll() to go no further until they're all completed.

Comment: And likewise, the delegate provided to `ContinueWith` won't execute until the task has completed.  `await` is just a shorthand for adding continuations.  It's a useful shorthand, and it's much easier to use correctly, but using `ContinueWith` properly is not fundamentally any different.

Comment: @digimunk this is a UI load event and calling Await on the Task.WhenAll will cause the UI to lock.

Comment: Event handler can be `async`, in that case the wouldn't be any UI locking.

Comment: @goroth Awaiting a task from the UI thread won't lock it, no.  Synchronously waiting on it would, but not awaiting it.